# Приставки "з" не бывает

Tags: орфография

Ещё со школы помню это правило. А почему из всех приставок на з-с только для неё нет пары?

Comment: Причем, это касается только русского языка, что еще интереснее. В украинском очень даже бывает.

Comment: Когда говорят на з(с), подразумевают приставки из нескольких букв, оканчивающиеся  на з(с). А эта просто из одного звука состоит.

Comment: zjadłem (пол.) - съел

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Насчет приставок.
Это чисто орфографическое правило. 
Когда-то было решено, что приставки типа *раз*, *без*, *воз* и другие, исторически имевшие "З", перед гласными и звонкими отображаются в исходном виде, а перед глухими - с С. Так появились парные варианты. Но приставка **С** никогда не принадлежала к этой группе, она исторически писалась через С в соответствии со своей морфологией.
Поэтому "парные" варианты для неё и не нужны.

В тех же родственных языках (украинском), где влияние фонетического принципа на орфографию сильнее, в озвончаемых позициях приставка С может передаваться через З. 
Все эти правила были придуманы много позже разделения языков, поэтому друг на друга орфографии разных языков не повлияли.

Comment: В языке ничего не бывает просто по решению комиссии, решает не один-двое, а все носители языка, история языка даёт всему объяснение.

Comment: Это Вы к чему? O_o
Даже не знаю, что ответить...

Comment: Я о том, что парные варианты образовались не по решению орфографической комиссии,древнерусское розсолъ развилось в росолъ ещё в др.русском, так же как рассудок из др.русск.росудити, расудити (без удвоения С),в современном просто появилось удвоение,поэтому звуки/буквы одинаковые - или оба глухие, или оба звонкие,а уж потом к этому подтянули и другие написания слов, где были не удвоенные буквы, а разные - по аналогии.

Comment: >древнерусское розсолъ развилось в росолъ ещё в др.русском

:-) А где-нибудь в окрестностях Киева и сегодня можно услышать именно в таком произношении. **Роз-сол**. С явственным и чётким "З" и потом "С". И обе буквы "О" -- именно как "О", не "а".

Comment: Людмила, я не очень понимаю, какое все это имеет к вопросу, но все-таки...

>парные варианты образовались не по решению орфографической комиссии   
  
Именно по её решению. 

6. Писать приставки (из, воз, раз, роз, низ, без, чрез, через) перед гласными и звонкими согласными с «з», но заменять «з» буквой «с» перед глухими согласными, в том числе и перед «с» (извините, воззвание, низвергать, безвольный, чрезвычайно, — исправить, воспитать, всхожие семена, расстаться, роспись, ниспосланный, бесполезно, чересполосица, чересседельник).

Comment: http://ru.wikisource.org/wiki/%D0%9E_%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%28%D0%9B%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%29

Дореформенное написание было именно разсолъ, разсудокъ и проч.
http://www.dorev.ru/ru-index.html?l=d0   
  
Да, ***фонетическое*** оглушение фозникло гораздо раньше, с падегин редуыированных, но это касалось всех преставок, в т.ч. и сосбтвенно ***С/З***.  Отвечая, и имел в виду ***орфографические*** правила.

Comment: Да, мы с Вами действительно говорим на разные темы,Вы приводите словарь 1914 года, а я зациклилась на древнерусском, потом орфография менялась, конечно, не раз, после революции просто всё свели к единому написанию.Но приставки С- это не касалось, она оформилась из СЪ, а ЗЪ не было.

Answer (score 4):

Потому что  в древнерусском был предлог СЪ(Ъ утратился или прояснился в О)- из и.-е. *son-из -направление сверху вниз, вдоль, в продолжение. Оттенки значения отражены в праслав. Из и.-е.*son - су(через юс )в именах супруг, сутки,а напрямую из праслав.*sъn - сн-, с-(в глаголах-сказать),лат.cum/com-с-вместе, греч.kata-вниз -катастрофа. Как видите, звонкому З там никак места нет, а вот в украинском в рез. озвончения -з(з тобою) ,а перед группой согласных-зi(зi мною).

Answer (score 2):

> Мне интересно, почему скушные ответы активно плюсуются, а неординарные и познавательные - активно игнорируются??

Потому что "скушные" ответы даются профессионалами.  (К ним, в частности, я отношу 
Ларf и Людмилу).

А теперь, Дерзкий, грызите меня.